# how to remove negative sign from a characters or text?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Please help! How to remove the negative sign(-) from a characters or text? Let say I have this text -ABC. The output should be ABC.See sample below.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?  Look into the Replace function, your example also calls for the use of Trim

Comment: Hi Sir. I already used the Replace function but all the negative sign was removed. i only need to remove the negative sign from the first character. Example -ABC-xyz the output should be ABC-xyz

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

If there **IS** space between negative sigh & the first letter

`=IF(LEFT(A1,1)="-",MID(A1,FIND("-",A1,1)+2,LEN(A1)-FIND("-",A1,1)-1),"")`

If there **IS NOT** space between negative sigh & the first letter

`=IF(LEFT(A1,1)="-",MID(A1,FIND("-",A1,1)+1,LEN(A1)-FIND("-",A1,1)),"")`

Comment: This appears to remove the first character after the dash as well.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent as i can see from the picture upload by OP, there is a space between negative sign and the first letter. that why i modify the code to delete also the space

Comment: That's not how it looks like in his latest comment though :S

Comment: I would opt for `=IFERROR(TRIM(MID(A1,SEARCH("-",A1)+1,LEN(A1))),A1)` this would work on all possible examples.

Comment: @JvdV what will be happen if the cell contains more than one "-" as OP mention above?

Comment: @Error1004 now I see :). I though he meant to say value1 `-ABC`, value2 `-XYZ`. In that case `=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("-",TRIM(A1)),0)=1,TRIM(MID(A1,SEARCH("-",A1)+1,LEN(A1))),A1)` should work for all possible examples.